# Failed to display an error message page in my Android program

Tags: android

This is my very first Android program. Basically I check a condition and switch to an error message page. I am sure the error screen codes (ErrorScreen.java) are correct.

```
public class ABC extends Activity {
...
private void init(){
   if (i > 0)
   {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, ErrorScreen.class));
       finish();
   }
 }
}
```

Every time it runs to 'startActivity', the program will crash. Did I miss something?
The log shows:

```
12-13 17:05:07.205: D/AndroidRuntime(30890): Shutting down VM
12-13 17:05:07.205: W/dalvikvm(30890): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c6d1f8)
12-13 17:05:07.215: E/AndroidRuntime(30890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 17:05:07.215: E/AndroidRuntime(30890): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-13 17:05:07.215: E/AndroidRuntime(30890):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3252)
12-13 17:05:07.215: E/AndroidRuntime(30890):    at  android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3359)
12-13 17:05:07.215: E/AndroidRuntime(30890):    at   com.stoyan.abc.ABC.init(ABC.java:373)
12-13 17:05:07.215: E/AndroidRuntime(30890):    at com.stoyan.abc.ABC.analyze(ABC.java:83)
```

Comment: Please attach LogCat output

Comment: When is the `init` method called?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register ErrorScreen class in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

**-** First makes sure you have added `ErrorScreen Activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**-** I am not sure when you are calling this `init()` method, but i am sure this piece of code should be triggered as soon as you check the condition, for example inside the `onClick()` method of `OnClickListener`.